# How to use arrays and loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have to write a program where a `studentID` array is displayed, followed by a `randomNumber` array. The result should look like this:

studentID array: 1, 0, 7, 4, 9

randomNum array: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 9, 11, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 19

1 was found in the random array

7 was found in the random array

This is what I have written so far, but I don't know how to display the random array:

```
var studentID = [1,0,7,9,2,6,3];
document.getElementById("ma").innerHTML = "studentID array: " + studentID;

var randomNum = new Array(parseInt(studentID));

for(var i = 0; i < studentID.length; i++){
    randomNum[i] = parseInt(Math.random() * 20);
    document.getElementById("par").innerHTML += "randomNum array: " + randomNum[i]);        
}
```

complete instructions:

4. Create an array and use the digits of your student id to populate it:
   a. Use only one instance of the repeated digits (i.e Student ID: 1070419170)
   var studentID = [1, 0, 7, 4, 9];
5. Create another array with 20 entries as followed:
   a. Use Math.random() method to generate numbers between zero and 20 to
   populate each entry of your array (hint: loop).
   b. Sort the entries in this array from lowest to highest
   array.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
6. Display values of each array on a separate paragraph (   ).
   (50 Marks so far)
7. Loop through the values in studentID array, retrieving one entry at a time, then check if
   you find at least one match in random number array. (40 Marks)
   a. If a match was found, display a message in a new paragraph:
   i.e

   7 was found in the random array

   see sample output at the end of this document

Comment: [JavaScript Array indexOf() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

Comment: [JavaScript Array join() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

Comment: It looks like you've forgotten to ask a question. What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: I can display for example: studentID array: 1, 0, 7, 4, 9. but I can't display randomNum array: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 9, 11, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 19 (this is an array with 20 indexes and is done with a loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I don't know how to display the random array"

- Use `Array.toString()` or `Array.join(delimiter)` to convert your array into a string.
- It is recommended to use `element.textContent` instead of `element.innerHTML`

```js
var array = new Array(20).fill(20).map(a => Math.trunc(Math.random() * a)).sort((a, b) => a - b);

document.getElementById("output").textContent = array.toString();
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: But how would I display this: randomNum array: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 9, 11, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 19 .... (the numbers that repeat are the indexes of studentID array)

Comment: @mannia You need to give us more information about how this 'randomNum' array should be build

Comment: Create another array with 20 entries as followed:
a. Use Math.random() method to generate numbers between zero and 20 to
populate each entry of your array (hint: loop).
b. Sort the entries in this array from lowest to highest
array.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
6. Display values of each array on a separate paragraph ( <p > </p> ).

Comment: And here's a sample output:   studentID array: 1, 0, 7, 4, 9
randomNum array: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 9, 11, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 19
1 was found in the random array
7 was found in the random array

Comment: @mannia Please include this information (minus the link) into your original question!

Answer (score 0):

Theres a mistake in the line you want to show the numbers, remove the parenthesis at the end and there you go